# How do I parse an HTML table within an HTML table?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I parse a table within a table for a simple web scraping application?

My process is:

- Create soup object of url
- find all tags with
- find  tags within the already found tables
- find the rows
- find the headers
- find the data in the table

HTML code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="660">
    <tbody><tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Time</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Weather</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Temperature</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Dewpoint</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Humidity</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Pressure</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Winds</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Visibility</th>
    </tr>
<tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">12:11AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Cloudy</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25°F/-4°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25°F/-4°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">100%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSE&nbsp;7 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">12:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Cloudy</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">100%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSE&nbsp;5 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">1:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Partly Cloudy</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25°F/-4°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">93%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">S&nbsp;5 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">2:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">19°F/-7°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">19°F/-7°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">100%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSE&nbsp;7 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">3:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">19°F/-7°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">86%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;6 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">4:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">19°F/-7°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">86%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;8 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">5:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">18°F/-8°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">80%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">WSW&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">6:07AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Freezing Fog</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">21°F/-6°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">18°F/-8°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">86%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NW&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.5mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">6:29AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Freezing Fog</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">100%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NW&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">6:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Freezing Fog</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">100%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">WNW&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mist and Fog</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">18°F/-8°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">93%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SE&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">8:09AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mist and Fog</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">18°F/-8°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">93%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">ESE&nbsp;5 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">5mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">8:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25°F/-4°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">93%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;9 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">9:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">36°F/2°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">27°F/-3°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;6 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">10:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">43°F/6°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">46%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;10 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">11:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">48°F/9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">21°F/-6°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">34%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;9 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">12:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Partly Cloudy</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">52°F/11°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">9°F/-13°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">17%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SW&nbsp;8 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">1:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Partly Cloudy</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">54°F/12°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">5°F/-15°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">14%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">N&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">2:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">57°F/14°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7°F/-14°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">13%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">WNW&nbsp;6 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">3:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">57°F/14°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">3°F/-16°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">11%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NNW&nbsp;7 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">4:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">59°F/15°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">3°F/-16°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">10%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NW&nbsp;12 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">5:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">57°F/14°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">-6°F/-21°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">W&nbsp;20 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">6:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">54°F/12°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">-2°F/-19°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">10%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">WNW&nbsp;15 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">46°F/8°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">5°F/-15°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">18%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NW&nbsp;7 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">8:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">45°F/7°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">9°F/-13°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">W&nbsp;7 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">9:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">41°F/5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">12°F/-11°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">31%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NW&nbsp;9 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">10:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">43°F/6°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">14°F/-10°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">31%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">WNW&nbsp;10 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">11:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">34°F/1°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">65%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">N&nbsp;21 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25mi.</span></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I want to grab all of the data in the last line (

Here is what I have so far:

```
  try:
    resp = urlopen(url)
  except URLError as e:
    print "An error occured fetching %s \n %s" %  (url, e.reason)
    return 1
  soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.read(), 'lxml')

  # get outer table
  try:
    outerTables = soup.findAll('table')
  except AttributeError as e:
    print "No tables found, exciting"
    return 1

  # get inner table
  try:
    for table in outerTables:
      innerTables = soup.findAll('table')
  except AttributeError as e:
    print "No inner tables found"
    return 1

  # get rows
  try:
    for table in innerTables:
      rows = soup.findAll('tr')
  except AttributeError as e:
    print "No rows found"
    return 1

  # get headers
  headers = []
  try:
    for row in rows:
      markup = soup.findAll('th')
  except AttributeError as e:
    print "No headers found"
    return 1
  for i in range(0,len(markup)):
    headers.append(markup[i].string)
```

Am I on the right path here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html has one table with headers which are the *th* tags, some rows which are the *tr* tags and inside the rows is the data you want inside the *td* tags:

```
h = """<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" width="660">
      <tr bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Time</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Weather</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Temperature</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Dewpoint</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Humidity</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Pressure</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Winds</th>
        <th class="IntWxHeader">Visibility</th>
    </tr>
<tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">12:11AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Cloudy</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25°F/-4°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25°F/-4°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">100%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSE&nbsp;7 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">12:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Cloudy</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">100%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSE&nbsp;5 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">1:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Partly Cloudy</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25°F/-4°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">93%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">S&nbsp;5 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">2:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">19°F/-7°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">19°F/-7°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">100%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSE&nbsp;7 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">3:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">19°F/-7°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">86%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;6 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">4:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">19°F/-7°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">86%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;8 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">5:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">18°F/-8°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">80%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">WSW&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">6:07AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Freezing Fog</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">21°F/-6°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">18°F/-8°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">86%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NW&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.5mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">6:29AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Freezing Fog</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">100%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NW&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">6:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Freezing Fog</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">100%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">WNW&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mist and Fog</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">18°F/-8°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">93%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SE&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">8:09AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mist and Fog</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">18°F/-8°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">16°F/-9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">93%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">ESE&nbsp;5 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">5mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">8:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25°F/-4°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">93%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;9 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">9:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">36°F/2°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">27°F/-3°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;6 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">10:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">43°F/6°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">46%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;10 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">11:55AM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">48°F/9°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">21°F/-6°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">34%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SSW&nbsp;9 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">12:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Partly Cloudy</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">52°F/11°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">9°F/-13°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">17%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">SW&nbsp;8 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">1:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Partly Cloudy</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">54°F/12°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">5°F/-15°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">14%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">N&nbsp;3 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">2:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">57°F/14°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7°F/-14°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">13%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">WNW&nbsp;6 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">3:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">57°F/14°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">3°F/-16°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">11%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NNW&nbsp;7 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">4:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">59°F/15°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">3°F/-16°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">10%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NW&nbsp;12 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">5:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">57°F/14°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">-6°F/-21°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">W&nbsp;20 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">6:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">54°F/12°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">-2°F/-19°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">10%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">WNW&nbsp;15 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">7:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">46°F/8°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">5°F/-15°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">18%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NW&nbsp;7 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">70mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">8:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">45°F/7°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">9°F/-13°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">W&nbsp;7 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">9:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">41°F/5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">12°F/-11°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">31%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">NW&nbsp;9 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#E6EFFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">10:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">43°F/6°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">14°F/-10°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">31%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">WNW&nbsp;10 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25mi.</span></td></tr><tr style="line-height:20pt; background-color:#F8FBFF;"><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">11:55PM</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">Mostly Clear</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">34°F/1°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">23°F/-5°C</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">65%</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">0.00</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">N&nbsp;21 MPH</span></td><td align="center"><span style="font-size: 16px;">25mi.</span></td></tr>
/table>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
table = soup.find("table")
# get all the headers/columns
headers = [th.text for th in table.find_all("th")]
print(", ".join(headers))
# select all rows in the table, after the first as the first includes the th tags which we already have.
rows = table.select("tr + tr")
# iterate over all the trs/rows
for row in rows:
   # pull the text from each td
    print(", ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td"))
```

Which would give you:

```
Time, Weather, Temperature, Dewpoint, Humidity, Pressure, Winds, Visibility
12:11AM, Cloudy, 25°F/-4°C, 25°F/-4°C, 100%, 0.00, SSE 7 MPH, 7mi.
12:55AM, Mostly Cloudy, 23°F/-5°C, 23°F/-5°C, 100%, 0.00, SSE 5 MPH, 7mi.
1:55AM, Partly Cloudy, 25°F/-4°C, 23°F/-5°C, 93%, 0.00, S 5 MPH, 7mi.
2:55AM, Mostly Clear, 19°F/-7°C, 19°F/-7°C, 100%, 0.00, SSE 7 MPH, 7mi.
3:55AM, Mostly Clear, 23°F/-5°C, 19°F/-7°C, 86%, 0.00, SSW 6 MPH, 7mi.
4:55AM, Mostly Clear, 23°F/-5°C, 19°F/-7°C, 86%, 0.00, SSW 8 MPH, 7mi.
5:55AM, Mostly Clear, 23°F/-5°C, 18°F/-8°C, 80%, 0.00, WSW 3 MPH, 7mi.
6:07AM, Freezing Fog, 21°F/-6°C, 18°F/-8°C, 86%, 0.00, NW 3 MPH, 0.5mi.
6:29AM, Freezing Fog, 16°F/-9°C, 16°F/-9°C, 100%, 0.00, NW 3 MPH, 0.25mi.
6:55AM, Freezing Fog, 16°F/-9°C, 16°F/-9°C, 100%, 0.00, WNW 3 MPH, 0.25mi.
7:55AM, Mist and Fog, 18°F/-8°C, 16°F/-9°C, 93%, 0.00, SE 3 MPH, mi.
8:09AM, Mist and Fog, 18°F/-8°C, 16°F/-9°C, 93%, 0.00, ESE 5 MPH, 5mi.
8:55AM, Mostly Clear, 25°F/-4°C, 23°F/-5°C, 93%, 0.00, SSW 9 MPH, 7mi.
9:55AM, Mostly Clear, 36°F/2°C, 27°F/-3°C, 70%, 0.00, SSW 6 MPH, 25mi.
10:55AM, Mostly Clear, 43°F/6°C, 23°F/-5°C, 46%, 0.00, SSW 10 MPH, 70mi.
11:55AM, Mostly Clear, 48°F/9°C, 21°F/-6°C, 34%, 0.00, SSW 9 MPH, 70mi.
12:55PM, Partly Cloudy, 52°F/11°C, 9°F/-13°C, 17%, 0.00, SW 8 MPH, 70mi.
1:55PM, Partly Cloudy, 54°F/12°C, 5°F/-15°C, 14%, 0.00, N 3 MPH, 70mi.
2:55PM, Mostly Clear, 57°F/14°C, 7°F/-14°C, 13%, 0.00, WNW 6 MPH, 70mi.
3:55PM, Mostly Clear, 57°F/14°C, 3°F/-16°C, 11%, 0.00, NNW 7 MPH, 70mi.
4:55PM, Mostly Clear, 59°F/15°C, 3°F/-16°C, 10%, 0.00, NW 12 MPH, 70mi.
5:55PM, Mostly Clear, 57°F/14°C, -6°F/-21°C, 7%, 0.00, W 20 MPH, 70mi.
6:55PM, Mostly Clear, 54°F/12°C, -2°F/-19°C, 10%, 0.00, WNW 15 MPH, 70mi.
7:55PM, Mostly Clear, 46°F/8°C, 5°F/-15°C, 18%, 0.00, NW 7 MPH, 70mi.
8:55PM, Mostly Clear, 45°F/7°C, 9°F/-13°C, 23%, 0.00, W 7 MPH, 25mi.
9:55PM, Mostly Clear, 41°F/5°C, 12°F/-11°C, 31%, 0.00, NW 9 MPH, 25mi.
10:55PM, Mostly Clear, 43°F/6°C, 14°F/-10°C, 31%, 0.00, WNW 10 MPH, 2
```

If you did have a table inside a table you would simply find the first then use `first_table.find("table")`, or if the table had a class or id you could maybe just use that to select the table directly.